# What does it mean to have 0x00 partition type?

Tags: partitioning, mount, mac, boot-partition, disk-management

I created a bootable pen-drive some time ago and recently I tried to mount it on Mac. It gave `device not readable error`. It was mounting perfectly on linux (ubuntu). I started to investigate why that would happen and I found out that the partition type is `0x00` as shown by the linux's disk utility.

I found out from [here](https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/PartTypes.htm) that it is not common to have `0x00` in partition type and it means unknown type. Is there a particular reason that bootable disk was 0x00 type?

Comment: Mac can't read Linux filesystems. What is the filesystem on the drive?

Comment: It is a bootable drive and partition type is showing 0x00

Comment: This question is about Mac. As at their site what this error means.

Comment: Mac was used for context. I want to understand why the drive which was created by ubuntu has 0x00

Comment: I recently flashed Zorin OS to a USB drive and I found the same thing: the partition has 0x00 as partition type. I think that that's because the partition has a ISO filesystem but it's a USB. So the OS does not recognize it as a common partition type. [[Disks app SCREENSHOT]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4VEG.png)